# DXF to SVG with element id from attributes

Tags: svg, inkscape, dxf

I am relatively new with SVG. I have a problem:

I have a DXF file with 10000 circles and each circle with a specific name in attributes. i want to convert to SVG but also need to identify each circle with ID as its attribute name. When i convert with inkscape, I am loosing attributes with a random circle ID.

Please suggest if there is any manual procedure in converting DXF to SVG preserving its attributes as element ID.

I tried by taking x and y coordinates from dxf file and manually written svg code, but the picture came skew than that is generated by inkscape. your kind support is really appreciated

Thanks a ton!!